# PopUp closes before showing Contact Form 7's after submit text

Tags: contact-form-7, elementor

I am using elementor's popup in wordpress to show my CF7 form. My issue is that the popup closes before it can show the after submit confirmation text.
What could I do in such a situation? That text is very important.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinitialize the form after the opening of the popup.

You can add a html widget in the page where the popup opens (Or in the footer, if opens in any part of the website) and paste the following code:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // More information about elementor popup events 
    // here https://developers.elementor.com/elementor-pro-2-7-popup-events/
    jQuery(document).on('elementor/popup/show', () => {
        wpcf7.init(jQuery(".wpcf7-form")[0]);
    });
});
</script>
```

Or even modify the functions.php (In the child theme if is necessary):

```
// Stop Elementor Popup from Closing after CF7 submission with no validation
function elementor_popup_cf7_fix() {
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    jQuery(document).on('elementor/popup/show', () => {
        for(var i = 0; i < jQuery(".wpcf7-form").length ; i++) {
            wpcf7.init(jQuery(".wpcf7-form")[i]);   
        }
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer',  'elementor_popup_cf7_fix' );
```

Source: https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/7798